# Ajax function doesn't seem working

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing an online application of tennis club management... (MVC 3, Entity Framework Code first,...)

I've an Interface that allows the user to consult the **available tennis court** :

[image]

**In my "AvailableCourtController", I've a function which return the tennis courts :**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetTennisCourt(DateTime date)
    {
        var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(c => c.Customer);

        foreach (var reservation in reservations)
        {

            //Verify that a court is available or not
            if (reservation.Date ==date)
            {
                if (date.Hour > reservation.FinishTime.Hour || date.Hour < reservation.StartTime.Hour)
                {
                    var id = reservation.TennisCourtID;

                    TennisCourt tennisCourt = (TennisCourt) db.TennisCourts.Where(t => t.ID == id);
                    tennisCourt.Available = true;
                    db.Entry(tennisCourt).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    var id = reservation.TennisCourtID;
                    TennisCourt tennisCourt = (TennisCourt) db.TennisCourts.Where(s => s.ID == id);
                    tennisCourt.Available = false;
                    db.Entry(tennisCourt).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        var courts = from c in db.TennisCourts
                     select c;
        courts = courts.OrderBy(c => c.ID);

        return Json(courts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
    }
```

**So, I would like to change the color of my label if the tennis court is busy or free... For that I use "Ajax":**

*"View"* *(What I've tried to make)*

```
<input id="datePicker" type= "text" onchange="loadCourts"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datePicker').datetimepicker();
</script>           

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadCourts() {
var myDate = $('#datePicker').value();

$.ajax({
    url: ("/AvailableCourt/GetTennisCourt?date=myDate "),
    success: function (data) {
        alert('test');
        //change label's color                                    
    }
});
}
</script>
```

I never get the message "test"... So I have make something wrong with my Ajax function or my controller's method... My goal is to get the tennis court, check if they're free or not and change color in red if busy, and in green if free...

**Can you help me to find what I'm doing wrong please?**  Sorry :( But I'm a beginner with Ajax...

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors with firebug/chrome dev tools?  Have you tried putting a break point on the var myDate = line and seeing if it reaches there?

Comment: Also.. using things like onchange is considered bad practice.. it's better to do $(document).ready(function () { $('#datePicker').change(loadCourts); });

Comment: Yes, I'm using firebug, I never reach the "Ajax" function... But my "js" function seems working...

Comment: Even if the code doesnt throw an error, Firebug will show you the response coming back from the AJAX call. I can't imagine doing AJAX development without such a tool.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I also believe the ajax type should be 'POST' and the controller action should be marked as `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: Francesco, you should specify an "error" function along with your "sucess" so that your users can be notified if something goes wrong in the ajax call. it'll help you troubleshoot dev issues like this one. Your AJAX call is returning a 500 (probably) but your AJAX setup hasn't been told to do anything if a 500 comes back.

Comment: I will add an error function ;) Thanks

Comment: Finally he reaches my Ajax function ! But I get 2 errors on Firebug, I'll add a new post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datetimepicker() call has to occur inside of a document.ready.  Here is the corrected code:

```
<input id="datePicker" type= "text"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datePicker').datetimepicker();
        $('#datePicker').change(loadCourts);
    });

    function loadCourts() {
        var myDate = $('#datePicker').val();

        $.post({
            data: "{ 'date' : " + myDate + " }",
            url: (@Url.Action("AvailableCourt", "GetTennisCourt"),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('test');
                //change label's color                                    
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

}

Comment: Fixed base on things CAbbott had noticed.

Comment: Switched to using $.post.. moving the data to json and using the correct HtmlHelper for your url

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my problem still persists... My Ajax function is not call... I'll update my first post... When I use a breakPoint in Firebug, he never stops..

Comment: Finally he reaches my Ajax function ! But I get 2 errors on Firebug, I'll add a new post

Answer (score 3):

This line is not passing a date in the querystring:

```
url: ("/AvailableCourt/GetTennisCourt?date=myDate "),
```

should be:

```
url: ("/AvailableCourt/GetTennisCourt?date=" + myDate),
```

**EDIT**: Also you're not getting the value correctly:

```
var myDate = $('#datePicker').value();
```

should be:

```
var myDate = $('#datePicker').val();
```

Comment: Good call. I suspect his page is throwing an error when it trying to parse the string 'myDate' as a date, and so the AJAX code never runs the 'success' function.

Comment: Thank you for your response ;) I'll check that

Comment: Finally he reaches my Ajax function !  But I get 2 errors on Firebug, I'll add a new post

Answer (score 1):

Your url is wrong :-)

Should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/AvailableCourt/GetTennisCourt?date="+myDate, // without ( )
    success: function (data) {
        alert('test');
        //change label's color                                    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Finally he reaches my Ajax function ! But I get 2 errors on Firebug, I'll add a new post... If you want to help me I will be more grateful

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @CAbbott that your URL was not created correctly.  But with date values (and multiple query string values in general), you may be better off adding your date parameter in a data object literal in your ajax call:

```
function loadCourts() {
    var myDate = $('#datePicker').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: ("/AvailableCourt/GetTennisCourt"),
        data: { date: myDate },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('test');
            //change label's color                                    
        }
    });
}
```

jQuery will append your data onto the querystring for you and format it appropriately.

From the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs:

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a
>   query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Finally he reaches my Ajax function ! But I get 2 errors on Firebug, I'll add a new post... If you want to help me I will be more grateful

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: "{ 'date' : " + myDate + " }",
    url: '/AvailableCourt/GetTennisCourt',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 8000, // 8 second timeout
    success: function (msg) {
    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
        if (t === "timeout") {
            HandleTimeout();
        } else {
                    alert(t);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Finally he reaches my Ajax function ! But I get 2 errors on Firebug, I'll add a new post... If you want to help me I will be more grateful